# Existe referencia para system.web no asp.net core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou montando um Helper e preciso usar o HttpRequestBase no asp.net core, mais não encontro uma referência
Como eu poderia adicionar ?

Agradeço

Comment: Provavelmente você quer isso: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest

Answer (score 0):

Não, o `system.web` não faz parte do .Net Core. Você pode conferir [nesse catálogo](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web.Services).

O equivalente no .Net Core o @LINQ já respondeu no comentário: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest

**Referência:**

- https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web.Services